# How to find villages?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

While playing Minecraft Xbox 360 Edition, I tried to find a village, however I can't seem to find any. Are there any tips on how to encounter a village? Thanks.

Comment: Try generating a new world, in minecraft Xbox 360 edition, worlds are limited, so there is a chance of not getting a village in your world. -1 for lack of detail.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question with a definite answer. Try a new world, as suggested, or just keep looking, you have to find one eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try generating a new world. In Minecraft Xbox 360 edition, worlds are limited, so there is a chance of not getting a village in your world.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to find a village is to go to a dessert biome as it is the flattest biome in the game.

If you are lucky enough you could find a temple which has diamonds in it **(Read the wiki if you see one it is explosive).**

The dessert biome even has spawners which are at the sound level where your character starts hearing stuff. With it you can make a exp farm which you need to go on youtube to find one because I'm to lazy to search one for you.

Answer (score 3):

Best option, create creative mode map, once in fly around and if you like it save it, go back to menu write down the code of the map, delete it then recreate the same map in survival.

I have a map I like, I have one map creative one survival, I can explore with one and work with other.

Easiest way people.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find my first village in the Xbox 360 version.  What I did was build a boat and sail around the outside of the world.  This gives you kind of a wide search area that you can cover rapidly.

After that, if you can't find any villages on the land near the edge of the world, make a map (or use the one you spawn in the world with) to systematically search the world for them.

The village structures should be visible from a distance, and they're always on the surface, so caves aren't worth looking in.  Using the map, you should be able to see where you've already been and what directions have land that is unexplored.

It's possible that your world spawned without villages, though, so even after searching the whole map you may find that there isn't one.  There's not much that can be done in this case, I'm afraid, unless you're in Creative and can spawn villagers yourself.

Comment: I know you can spawn *villagers* in creative mode, but can you spawn *villages*?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot spawn villages in creative mode. You can build them, but you are only able to spawn villagers. In PE minecraft, some good village seeds are kop and village pls.

Comment: They weren't asking if you could spawn villages, but for tips on finding them.

Answer (score -1):

Just go into creative and build a Village in a spot you like then switch to survival and start playing, I'm sure there are villages in your world but it's gonna suck. The first one i found was on the edge of the map in the ocean. It's had a small grass path and wooden plank path around the two houses with a few farms the rest was deep ocean and my villagers drowned so I had to go in creative and spawn new villagers but because that was useless they just drowned so i built an island around it and put a fence up so my villagers didn't die.